# Using a CommonOpenFileDialog to select a folder but still show files within the folder in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, openfiledialog

I'm trying to use `CommonOpenFileDialog` to allow users to select a folder, but also view the files that within the folder in the dialog.  Currently my code allows the user to only select a folder, but files within it are hidden, which causes users to think they have selected a wrong (empty) folder.

```
using (var dlg = new CommonOpenFileDialog()
{
    Title = "Select folder to import from",
    AllowNonFileSystemItems = true,
    IsFolderPicker = true,
    EnsurePathExists = true,
    Multiselect = false,
    ShowPlacesList = true
})
{
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
    {
        //Do things with the selected folder and the files within it...
    }
}
```

How can I achieve my goal for applications targeting Windows 10?

<sub>**NOTE:** There is a very similar question titled "[How can I make CommonOpenFileDialog select folders only, but still show files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142109/how-can-i-make-commonopenfiledialog-select-folders-only-but-still-show-files)".  This question already has good answers, **however, none of the solutions work in Windows 10**.  Because the existing question is outdated (asked over 9 years ago) and doesn't apply for Windows 10, this question is specifically asking for a solution that works on a Windows 10 device.</sub>

Comment: I sympathize with your dilemma. Without rolling your own dialog, it appears this may not be doable using the common dialogs in Windows 10. Have you considered using the `OpenFileDialog`, forcing the user “pick” one of the displayed files in the folder they want, then only use the folder path after that? I can post code for this, however it is simply an `OpenFileDialog` that uses… `string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(dlg.FileName);`

Comment: Thanks @JohnG.  I have considered that, but I assumed there must be a better solution.  I assume many people have ran into this same issue with the current dialogs provided in .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is not possible with the CommonOpenFileDialog
See: [How to use IFileDialog with FOS_PICKFOLDER while still displaying file names in the dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269696/how-to-use-ifiledialog-with-fos-pickfolder-while-still-displaying-file-names-in)

The only way is to create your own custom dialog or you can use folder dialog with P/Invoke (based on SHBrowseForFolder like `FolderBrowserDialog`).
See: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.shbrowseforfolder

Copy the class from the link above and add the option `BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES`.

```
public string SelectFolder(string caption, string initialPath, IntPtr parentHandle)
{
    _initialPath = initialPath;
    ...
    bi.ulFlags = BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE | BIF_SHAREABLE | BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES;
```

Now files are displayed in the dialog unfortunately only like `FolderBrowserDialog`.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to use something similar? Handle `FolderChanging` event and read the folder name?

```
private string SelectFolder()
{
    using (var dlg = new CommonOpenFileDialog()
    {
        Title = "Select folder to import from",
        AllowNonFileSystemItems = true,
        IsFolderPicker = true,
        EnsurePathExists = true,
        Multiselect = false,
        ShowPlacesList = true,
        InitialDirectory = "C:\\" //This must be handled manually
    })
    {
        dlg.FolderChanging += Dlg_FolderChanging;
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
        {
            //Do things with the selected folder and the files within it...
            string selectedFolder = dlg.InitialDirectory;
            string dlgFileName = dlg.FileName;
            if (Directory.Exists(dlgFileName))
                selectedFolder = dlgFileName;
            else if (File.Exists(dlgFileName))
                selectedFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(dlgFileName);
            else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastKnownFolder))
                selectedFolder = lastKnownFolder;

            return selectedFolder;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private string lastKnownFolder = "";

private void Dlg_FolderChanging(object sender, CommonFileDialogFolderChangeEventArgs e)
{
    lastKnownFolder = e.Folder;
}
```